# stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from:) return value equivalent

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, wkwebview

I know that this question seems to have been asked but I have a different problem with this method.

`UIWebView's` - `stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from:)` is synchronously returning a `String?` value.

The `WKWebView` equivalent `evaluateJavaScript(_:completionHandler:)` works with a complitionHandler.

I'm working with legacy code and I have `stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from:)` affecting thousands of lines in the code and can be found everywhere and in a lot of functions that return values (not using blocks).

very simple example -

```
@discardableResult func js(_ script: String) -> String? {
        let callback = self.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: script)
        if callback!.isEmpty { return nil }
        return callback
    }
```

now that I'm changing to `evaluateJavaScript(_:completionHandler:)` I will need the `js(script:)` method to be handled with a block, and methods that use that method needs to change and so on...

I think that in order to fix this without changing all my code I need `evaluateJavaScript(_:completionHandler:)` to synchronously return `String?`.

Does anybody know how this can be achieved? or maybe have a different solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it -

Add this to your `WKWebview` extension to wrap `evaluateJavaScript(_:completionHandler:)` in a synchronous warp like in `UIWebview` -

```
open func stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from script: String) -> String?
        {
            var finished = false
            var stringResult: String? = nil

            evaluateJavaScript(script) { (result, error) in

                if error == nil, let result = result
                {
                    stringResult = String(describing: result)
                }

                finished = true
            }

            while !finished
            {
                RunLoop.current.run(mode: .default, before: Date.distantFuture)
            }

            return stringResult
        }
```

I'm not sure what types can be returned in the `result` so watch out for that. other then that works great.